# On codaset, in a ticket description: is it possible to render raw text instead of markdown processed markup?

Tags: text, markdown, codaset

Well, everything is in the title ;-)

Thanks

Fro_oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codaset twitter answer :

> All descriptions are rendered via Markdown by default, and that cannot be disabled.